# webrtcbin video latency increases when an audio source is added

Tags: gstreamer

The following test is done via a single laptop with a single server running GStreamer.

I have a pretty basic pipeline:

Single Connection

```
audio: no audio connection (don't send audio to the same endpoint)
video: webrtcibin -> dec -> depay -> videoscale -> textoverlay -> tee -> compositor -> enc -> pay -> webrtcbin
```

Glass-to-glass here is about 170 ms with 40 RTT on the network. It's pretty good.

Dual Media Connection

```
// Connection 1

audio: webrtcibin -> dec -> depay -> tee -> audiomixer -> enc -> webrtcbin
video: webrtcibin -> dec -> depay -> videoscale -> textoverlay -> tee -> compositor -> enc -> pay ->  webrtcbin

// audio and video cross over into each other's audiomixer and compositor elements

// Connection 2

audio: webrtcibin -> dec -> depay -> tee -> audiomixer -> enc -> pay ->  webrtcbin
video: webrtcibin -> dec -> depay -> videoscale -> textoverlay -> tee -> compositor -> enc -> pay ->  webrtcbin
```

For some reason, sending audio / video from each connections corresponding `tee` elements
to the opposite `audiomixer` / `compositor` causes the queues in `webrtcbin` which are normally empty to fill up quite quickly.

Is there some caution I should be taking here when aggregating two live sources in this manner?

---

**RELATED**

I came across this https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gstreamer/-/issues/1261 which seems related.

It appears many people are running into the problem whereby sending audio and video through WebRTCbin incurs far higher latency than when sending just video. That coincides with why my single connection test performs better as there is no audio connection.

The outcome of that thread seems to be that sending audio and video through two separate WebRTCbins is the only solution they came across. But that’s not ideal as it could cause sync issues I believe?

TL;DR

Why does WebRTCBin incur extremely high latency (700 ms+) when audio and video are processed (whereas just video is low - 150 ms)?

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this increased latency when processing both audio and video is often related to the synchronization mechanisms and buffer management within the WebRTCbin element.

In the case of your pipeline with two media connections, where audio and video cross over into each other's audiomixer and compositor elements, it's possible that the queues in the WebRTCbin element are filling up quickly due to synchronization issues between the audio and video streams.

You could try changing the **buffer size and configuration**, or looking into **synchronization mechanisms** gstreamer provides various elements and mechanisms for audio-video synchronization, maybe look into elements like **audiomixer** and **videomixer**, and the most obvious one is so check if gstreamer is up to date.

Comment: That was my suspicion as well. I've been playing around with the parameters in the aggregators, but to no avail. I have a feeling that the two Webrtcbins are trying to synchronize against the two RTP endpoints. What's odd though is that they're the same machine. But you're right, it could be the crossing over of two live  media streams that's causing this. Perhaps its due to one set of media streams connecting after the other. Whats interesting is that the last endpoint to join ends up with the lowest latency.

Comment: AKA, if a webrtcbin already has an aggregator (audiomixer) and a new connection is made to it from another webrtcbin, the latency climbs for that first webrtcbin. The second which receives media from the first (but was created then and there) does not see the same latency as the first.

Comment: This answer looks like it might be ChatGPT to me. I'm not absolutely certain, but I'd be a little sceptical that it's accurate

Comment: It could be but it also aligns with https://gstconf.ubicast.tv/videos/synchronised-multi-room-media-playback-and-distributed-live-media-processing-and-mixing-with-gstreamer/

I would need specifics to close this question anyways.

Comment: @DavidW: Maybe. The last paragraph has several human elements. It could a mix of human and [not human](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SRKjf8b4f2E&t=1m52s).